# How can I tell if there is anything for Amylase to work on?

Tags: wine

Because I don't have any Amylase to platy with (yet), I'm looking for a way to check if it would have any effect that's cheaper and/or simpler than finding some place that sells the stuff. (Heck even with some in hand, I'm not sure how I'd know if it did anything.)

Some background, my objective isn't beer or wine (thought I don't mind if that's what I get) but rather I want to turn some fruit juice (pineapple for now) into a base for a steak marinade and I'm trying to remove any complex carbohydrates that would char or caramelize on a flat iron grill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm sure you know (but just in case) any unfermented sugars remaining in the juice will certainly caramelize.

To find out if starches are present, you could either try a Google—e.g. 'pineapple juice composition'—or hike down to the drugstore and get the smallest bottle of Tincture of Iodine they have in stock. Tincture of Iodine (the yellow stuff) will turn purply-black in the presence of starch. Happy grilling!

[ Edit: for all I know, Iodophor—a sterilant commonly used in brewing—may do the same. ]

Comment: Do sugars not count as complex carbohydrates? (I was assuming "complex" was more than ~3-4 carbons) -- Good idea, I suspect that Tincture of Iodine is more readily available Amylase.